# Why do we need to add brackets to lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda

Why do we need to add parentheses when adding function as an expression to lambda?

```
def print_():
   print('hello')

show = lambda: print_

show()
```

gives `<function print_ at 0x0000019046503560>`whereas

```
show1 = lambda: print_()

show1()
```

gives `hello`. Why this behaviour?

Comment: for the same reason you wrote `show()` with parentheses and not just `show`.

Comment: Keeping this question here for those who stumble upon the same idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494774/gog) provided the answer in a comment:

> For the same reason you wrote `show()` with parentheses and not just `show`.